# Example of a group such that the perfect maximal subgroup is $1$.

Tags: group-theory, maximal-subgroup

I an looking for an example of a group say $G$ such that the [perfect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_group) maximal subgroup is $1$.

---

I cannot find any references or come up with an example of my own. Could someone please cite a reference?

Comment: Doesn't every abelian group work?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your question, but abelian groups aren't perfect, since every commutator is trivial.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut sorry I got confused, yes every abelian group works but are there any non-abelian examples?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "perfect maximal subgroup"?

Comment: @spin by perfect maximal subgroup I mean, the biggest such subgroup (maximal) such that it is its own commutator (perfect)

Comment: Biggest means what? Largest possible order? Anyway, in any solvable group you have $[H,H] \lneqq H$ for any subgroup $H \neq 1$.

Comment: @spin yes, by biggest I meant of largest possible order. Does solvability then characterize all such groups?

Comment: You can phrase your question as: find a group whose only perfect subgroup is the trivial one, and thus remove the word maximal, which is confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you start with a finite group $G$ and construct the derived sequence $G_0=0$, $G_1=[G_0,G_0]$, $G_2=[G_1,G_1]$, $\dots$, then the intersection $\bigcap_{i\geq0}G_i$ is the unique maximal perfect subgroup of $G$ (in the sense that it is a perfect subgroup and contains all other perfect subgruops of $G$) If that intersection is trivial, then clearly one of the $G_i$ is trivial already, and your your is solvable.

If the group is infinite, you need to continue the derived sequence transfinitely, and intersect the whole thing to find the maximal perfect subgroup. Its triviality will not imply that the group is solvable, in general, because it may be the case that none of the initial, "finite" steps was trivial. Groups for which the transfinite sequence has trivial intersection are called hypoabelian.

Comment: Is there an easy example of an infinite group $G$ such that $\cap_{i \geq 0} G_i$ is not perfect?

Answer (score 3):

Nonabelian free groups have the desired property, and they are not solvable.

Comment: Googling taught me that free groups are residually solvable —  a nice paper on this is https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.0138 by Abdelrhman Elkasapy  and Andreas Thom.(They mention an amazing theorem of Friedrich Levi that says thart any nested series of subgroups which are characteristic in each other in a free group either stabilizes or has trivial intersection=